# Prolog: arithmetic problems while writing rpg stat printing program

Tags: prolog

I've been trying to write (as an exercise - to learn a bit about prolog) a small code fragment that prints all possible stat combinations for specific race from Pen and Paper RPG.

Relevant code fragment:

```
%abilities
ability(X) :-
    member(X, [str, dex, con, int, wis, cha]).

race(tiefling, planetouched, [[dex, 2], [int, 2], [cha, -2]], [infernalResistance,darkvision,skillAffinity(bluff),skillAffinity(hide)],rogue, 1, medium).
race(human, human, [], [quickToMaster, skilled], any, 0, medium).

racialAttributeBonus(Race, Stat, Bonus) :-
    race(Race, _, BonusList, _, _, _, _),
    member([Stat, Bonus], BonusList).

racialAttributeBonus(Race, Stat, 0) :-
    race(Race, _, BonusList, _, _, _, _),
    \+ member([Stat, _], BonusList).

%start ability points is 32

%first 6 points - 1 point per increase
%7, 8 - +2 per increase
%9, 10 - +3 per increase

statDiffCost(Diff, Cost) :-
    Range = [Diff, Cost],
    member(Range, [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [3, 3],
            [4, 4],
            [5, 5],
            [6, 6],
            [7, 8],
            [8, 10],
            [9, 13],
            [10, 16]
        ]).

raceAttribCost(Race, AttrName, AttrValue, Cost) :-
    number(AttrValue),
    racialAttributeBonus(Race, AttrName, Bonus),
    AttrDiff is AttrValue - Bonus - 8,
    statDiffCost(AttrDiff, Cost).

raceAttribCost(Race, AttrName, AttrValue, Cost) :-
    number(Cost),
    racialAttributeBonus(Race, AttrName, Bonus),
    statDiffCost(AttrDiff, Cost),
    AttrValue is AttrDiff + Bonus + 8.

raceAttributes(Race, Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha) :-
    StrCost + DexCost + ConCost + IntCost + WisCost + ChaCost is 32,
    raceAttribCost(Race, str, Str, StrCost),
    raceAttribCost(Race, dex, Dex, DexCost),
    raceAttribCost(Race, con, Con, ConCost),
    raceAttribCost(Race, int, Int, IntCost),
    raceAttribCost(Race, wis, Wis, WisCost),
    raceAttribCost(Race, cha, Cha, ChaCost).
```

However, I've run into couple of issues related to handling of numbers/arithmetics.

First, I would expect that

```
 raceAttributes(human, Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha).
```

Would print combination of parameters. Instead I get `false`.

Second, I've been unable to handle numerical parameters in `raceAttribCost` and `statDiffCost` in elegant fashion.

Basically, I had to create two versions of `raceAttribCost`, because depending on which parameter I specify, one of them will require "instantiated" variables at the right side of comparison.

So, I'd like to know how to

1. Make call to `raceAttributes` actually work.
2. Eliminate one of the versions of `raceAttribCost` and keep just one of them
3. (optionally) replace `statDiffCost` with something more compact.

All three are part of the same problem, which is mixing symbolic "calculations" and numerical arithmetics.

Advice?

P.S. I'm using SWI-PL 64bit on windows 7.

Comment: iHaveOneAdditionalCommentRegardingYourNamingConvention: you_will_find_using_underscores_much_easier_to_read_for_longer_names!

Comment: After years of camelCasing in C++, I'm unlikely to switch to anything else, sorry. Matter of habit.

Comment: Please see the [naming conventions](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#Hungarian) from the inventor of C++. Notably: "*I prefer to use underscores to separate words in an identifier (e.g, `element_count`) rather than alternatives, such as `elementCount` and `ElementCount`.*"

Comment: @mat: Well, I don't have to agree with inventor of C++ on that. Regarding camelcase, good thing is that pressing left shift is "free" (left hand barely ever moves from that spot), while underscore requires additional keypress. Also, in camelcase (when it is used properly) case of leading letter is used to distinguish between Type and variable/method/function. After camelcase, underscore notation looks strange and overly verbose in comparison. It is all logical. If you're interested, grab Qt 4/5 source and study them. They have very clean coding style.

Comment: @mat: Anyway, it is matter of taste, it is something I've given much though and it is habit, so the habit stays. Underscores work fine in languages without case sensitivity, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is extremely easy to solve with CLP(FD) constraints.

To your first question (why does this fail): `is/2` does not work with compound terms on its left hand side. You need `=:=/2` to compare the evaluation of arithmetic expressions. Still, simply replacing `is/2` with `=:=/2` does not work in your case due to uninstantiated variables.

To solve this, simply replace all occurrences of `is/2` with the CLP(FD) constraint `#=/2` in your program, and add `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` if necessary at the beginning of your program. This yields a much more general program.

Then, simply also remove the then unnecessary `number/1` goal, and remove superfluous clauses.

Example query and its result with the new version:

```
?- raceAttributes(human, Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha).
Str = Dex, Dex = Con, Con = Int, Int = 8,
Wis = Cha, Cha = 18 ;
Str = Dex, Dex = Con, Con = 8,
Int = 11,
Wis = 17,
Cha = 18 ;
Str = Dex, Dex = Con, Con = 8,
Int = 11,
Wis = 18,
Cha = 17 ;
etc.
```

Works exactly as expected, in all directions.

Comment: It works, thanks for the help/quick response. The funny thing is I came across mention of clfpd before posting but for some reason didn't give it a try :-\.

Comment: I highly recommend simply using CLP(FD) constraints for all integer arithmetic in your programs. You often get much more general programs at typically negligible additional cost. For example, with SWI-Prolog, I have `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` in my initialization file so that CLP(FD) constraints are automatically available for me at the toplevel, much like in other well-known systems such as GNU Prolog and B-Prolog.

Answer (score 3):

You could proceed like this:

1. Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for relational integer arithmetics:

   ```
     :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
   ```
2. Replace all uses of `is` with `#=`.
3. Remove all `number/1` goals.
4. Re-run your original query and report back:)

Comment: Works. Thanks for the help. I'm going to accept mat's answer though, since it is a bit more detailed.